# PHP: How remove an element of an array by length?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array output:

```
Array
(
 [0] => de la que fue colaborador Sicard, fue realizado ya en 1795 en la Décade philosophique y en el Magasin encyclopedique, y su aparición dos años después
 [1] => de la obligación de tener presentes incesantemente estas combinaciones {44}. Tienen un carácter más estable que las ideas, pero son también
 [2] => de la época X de su Esquisse dun tableau historique del progrès de lesprit humain, pero no apareció en ninguna de las versiones publicadas
 [3] => de la Asociación de bibliotecarios americanos, es una
}
```

Could you please help me to remove all elements with more than 100chars or 10 words?

This is my code.

Unfortunately the code provided by experts does not works when I am using variables:

```
<?php
function tag_contents($string, $tag_open, $tag_close){
   foreach (explode($tag_open, $string) as $key => $value) {
       if(strpos($value, $tag_close) !== FALSE){
            $result[] = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, $tag_close));;
       }
   }
   return $result;
}

$string = 'de la que fue colaborador Sicard, fue realizado ya en 1795 en la Décade philosophique y en el Magasin encyclopedique, y su aparición dos años después de la obligación de tener presentes incesantemente estas combinaciones {44}. Tienen un carácter más estable que las ideas, pero son también de la época X de su Esquisse dun tableau historique del progrès de en el lesprit humain, pero no apareció en ninguna de las versiones publicadas de la Asociación de bibliotecarios americanos, en el';
$strpos =  'de la' ;
$tagclose = 'en el';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(tag_contents($string , $strpos , $tagclose));
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

These strings are too short, but I want to know how I remove all elements with more than 'X'chars or 'X' words?

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: What you should do is loop over the array. Within the loop you write an statement that checks on stringlength.

Comment: You'll need to loop over your array, then do the test `if strlen($array[$i]) > 100 { unset($array[$i]); }`

Comment: I think you can use array_filter function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Just do a foreach and check the string length and word count. If any of them are above the limit, unset that index in the original array. Google and you shall find.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through array and check conditions fro length and words and unset array element according to it

```
$arr = Array
(
    0 => 'de la que fue colaborador Sicard, fue realizado ya en 1795 en la Décade philosophique y en el Magasin encyclopedique, y su aparición dos años después',
 1 => 'de la obligación de tener presentes incesantemente estas combinaciones {44}. Tienen un carácter más estable que las ideas, pero son también',
2 => 'de la época X de su Esquisse dun tableau historique del progrès de lesprit humain, pero no apareció en ninguna de las versiones publicadas',
3 => 'de la Asociación de bibliotecarios americanos, es una'
);
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
    if(strlen($value)>100 || str_word_count($value) > 10)
    {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
var_dump($arr);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/EeVR9)

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = [
    'de la que fue colaborador Sicard, fue realizado ya en 1795 en la Décade philosophique y en el Magasin encyclopedique, y su aparición dos años después',
    'de la obligación de tener presentes incesantemente estas combinaciones {44}. Tienen un carácter más estable que las ideas, pero son también',
    'de la época X de su Esquisse dun tableau historique del progrès de lesprit humain, pero no apareció en ninguna de las versiones publicadas',
    'de la Asociación de bibliotecarios americanos, es una'
];

$tmp = array_filter($tmp, function($currentElement) {
    return strlen($currentElement) <= 100 && str_word_count($currentElement) <= 10;
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. It works fine with the example placed, but when working with variables does not works to me. It is my full code:

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
foreach($yourArray as $key=>$value) { 
  if(strlen($value)>100 || str_word_count($value)>10) {
     unset($yourArray['key']);
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($yourArray);
```